# Issue with LiveActivity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, live

so here's my issue with LiveActivities. My code doesn't work, but no error is thrown...

Here's how I enable/disable the activity:

```
let helper = JourneyActivityHelper.shared
TagComponent(journey: journey)
    .onChange(of: journey.isTracked) { value in
        journey.isTracked ? helper.start(departureTime: departureTime, arrivalTime: arrivalTime, journey: journey) : helper.stop(departureTime: departureTime, arrivalTime: arrivalTime)
    }
```

Here's my helper class:

```
struct JourneyAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public typealias JourneyStatus = ContentState

    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var departureTime: Date
        var arrivalTime: Date
    }

    var journey: Journey
}

class JourneyActivityHelper {
    static let shared = JourneyActivityHelper()
    
    var activity: Activity<JourneyAttributes>?
    
    func start(departureTime: Date, arrivalTime: Date, journey: Journey) {
        // We check that activities can be enabled
        guard ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled else { return }

        // Initializing variables
        let initialState = JourneyAttributes.ContentState(departureTime: departureTime, arrivalTime: arrivalTime)
        let staleDate = departureTime <= Date() ? nil : departureTime
        let initialContent = ActivityContent(state: initialState, staleDate: staleDate)
        let attributes = JourneyAttributes(journey: journey)

        do {
            activity = try Activity.request(attributes: attributes, content: initialContent)
            print("New live activity activated!")
        } catch (let error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func stop(departureTime: Date, arrivalTime: Date) {
        Task {
            let finalState = JourneyAttributes.ContentState(departureTime: departureTime, arrivalTime: arrivalTime)
            let finalContent = ActivityContent(state: finalState, staleDate: nil)

            for activity in Activity<JourneyAttributes>.activities {
                await activity.end(finalContent, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's my LiveActivity code (Widget):

```
@main
struct TrainlyWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {

    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        TrainlyWidget()

        if #available(iOS 16.2, *) {
            ActivityConfiguration(for: JourneyAttributes.self) { context in
                LockScreenLiveActivity(context: context)
            } dynamicIsland: { context in
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me resolve my issue!

EDIT: What I expected: for my LiveActivity to show up. What happens: it doesn't show up!

Comment: _"My code doesn't work"_. What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected the LiveActivity to show up, and it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own issue. `departureTime` and `arrivalTime` (dates that were passed to `start()` and `stop()` functions) weren't actual dates. Therefore, the Live Activity didn't start because the dates were in the past (year 2000 instead of 2023)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).